# Lotus Notes Out Of Office for every email

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there a way to set up Lotus Notes to reply to EVERY email sent while out of office? I am running version 8.5.
Right now, by default, it only replies to the first message received and ignores the rest of them until it is reset. Possibly setting up some rule to assist with this?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to change that behavior. It's there to prevent out of office loops. You could modify the out of office agent, but that is likely something you don't have access to do.

Comment: Can I assume it would be best to create an Agent to Autorespond to all emails, and only enable it instead of the Out Of Office?

Comment: You can, but you need to be careful that it's smart enough to not generate loops where it's replying to out of office replies to it's initial out of office reply.